# Can't view SQLite database on Android Studio VD

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm new to Android studio but have been coding Java on Netbeans for many years. I've been trying to work out how to link SQLite to Android Studio. I managed to get the DatabaseHelper code working but I'm stuck on what I should do now? The database was already created on the SQLitebrowser. Here is the databasehelper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

String DB_PATH = null;

private static String DB_NAME = "Restaurant";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases";

}


/**
 * Creates an empty database on the system and rewrites it with my database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of the application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/*
 * Copies my database from the local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled by java
*/
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open the db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Closes them
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion>oldVersion){
        try{
            copyDataBase();
        } catch
            (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    }


}
```

What am I meant to do now to make this viewable in a list?

Comment: do you want get **.db** file ? OR anything else ?

Comment: I'm making an app to display a restaurant menu that is on an SQLite database, so I want to make the .db file to display in a list format

Comment: means that you are unable to generate .db file ? or you are not able to find .db file

Comment: I have made the.db file, it is located  in the assets folder but I'm not able to display it on the program? How do i extract information from the .db file that I have put in the program and display that information on the application screen

Comment: there are some database methods, which you have to implement to get and display data.

Comment: What are those methods? I've been trying to google to find them but I'm unable

Comment: please check https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html